# MySQL LEFT JOIN a different table based on a field value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, if-statement, join

I know similar questions have been presented a few times, but it seems these all related to the field value changing based on a specific field value. I actually want to join a completely different table based on the the field value of each record.

I think this is possible with a single query, but since the join table could change every record I'm not sure.

To clarify I have four tables; I am trying to join three of them in a single query. However the third table could be one of two tables depending on the value in each records field.

I would imagine it would look something like this, but its not working.

```
SELECT crm_deal . * , crm_deal_step.sort_order, COALESCE( CONCAT_WS(' ',crm_lead.first_name, crm_lead.last_name),CONCAT_WS(' ',customer.firstname, customer.lastname) ) AS contact_full_name
FROM  `crm_deal`
IF( crm_deal.deal_for = 'lead', LEFT JOIN crm_lead ON crm_deal.deal_for_id = crm_lead.lead_id, LEFT JOIN customer ON crm_deal.deal_for_id = customer.customer_id)
LEFT JOIN crm_deal_step ON crm_deal.deal_step_id = crm_deal_step.deal_step_id
```

Am I close? Is it possible or do I need to do a php loop and run a second query for every record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use if stat ment in a select statment.
But you can try this:

```
    SELECT crm_deal . * , crm_deal_step.sort_order, 
CASE WHEN crm_lead.first_name is not null AND
          crm_lead.last_name is not null
          THEN crm_lead.first_name+ ' '+crm_lead.last_name
          ELSE customer.firstname +' '+ customer.lastname
          END as contact_full_name
    FROM  `crm_deal`
    LEFT JOIN crm_lead ON crm_deal.deal_for_id = crm_lead.lead_id AND crm_deal.deal_for = 'lead' 
    LEFT JOIN customer ON crm_deal.deal_for_id = customer.customer_id AND crm_deal.deal_for <> 'lead' 
    LEFT JOIN crm_deal_step ON crm_deal.deal_step_id = crm_deal_step.deal_step_id
```

Comment: That works to populating the contact_full_name field with whatever table is first in the COALESCE function, but the other remains blank.

Comment: Thats because CONCAT_WS(' ',crm_lead.first_name, crm_lead.last_name) will never give you null. So CONCAT_WS(' ',customer.firstname, customer.lastname) will never be shown.

Comment: That did lead me to the solution though. with that addition I can now add an if statement to the select. Like this. SELECT crm_deal . * , crm_deal_step.sort_order, IF(CONCAT_WS(' ',customer.firstname, customer.lastname) = "", CONCAT_WS(' ',crm_lead.first_name, crm_lead.last_name), CONCAT_WS(' ',customer.firstname, customer.lastname)) AS contact_full_name
FROM  `crm_deal`
LEFT JOIN customer ON crm_deal.deal_for_id = customer.customer_id AND crm_deal.deal_for = 'customer' 
LEFT JOIN crm_lead ON crm_deal.deal_for_id = crm_lead.lead_id AND crm_deal.deal_for <> 'customer'

Comment: LEFT JOIN crm_deal_step ON crm_deal.deal_step_id = crm_deal_step.deal_step_id

Comment: If you would like to revise your answer I will select it as a solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I made some changes, this will help.